# Integrate: $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(-||\vec x||^2) ||\vec x||^{-m}\mathrm{d}\vec{x}$

Tags: normal-distribution, large-deviation-theory

Let $m,n$ be two positive integers with $0 < m < n$.

Can we integrate this:

$$I = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm{d}x_1 \dots \int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm{d}x_n  \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\right)^{-m/2} \exp\left(-\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\right)$$

If a closed analytical expression is not possible, what I really need is to evaluate a large deviation limit of the form:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n} \log I$$

where it is assumed that the ratio $m/n$ remains fixed.

Note that $I$ resembles a negative moment of the radious of a multivariate Gaussian.

I asked a very similar question here: [Integrate: $\int_0^1 ||\vec x||^{-m}\mathrm{d}\vec{x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3019159/10063). But note that this integral has different limits and a decaying quadratic exponential. Maybe I have better luck with this variant ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the homomorphism $x \mapsto \left( \|x\|, \dfrac{x}{\|x\|} \right)$ between $\mathbf{R}^d \setminus \{0\}$ and $(0, \infty) \times \mathbf{S}_{d-1}.$ By the change of measures formula, the integral becomes
$$\begin{align*}
\int\limits_0^\infty dr \int\limits_{\mathbf{S}_{d-1}} d\sigma_d\ e^{-r^2}r^{-m} r^{d-1} &= \sigma_{d-1}(\mathbf{S}_{d-1}) \int\limits_{0}^\infty dr\ e^{-r^2} r^{d-m-1} \\
&= \dfrac{\sigma_{d-1}(\mathbf{S}_{d-1})}{2} \int\limits_0^\infty dr\ e^{-r} r^{\frac{d-m-2}{2}} \\
&= \dfrac{\sigma_{d-1}(\mathbf{S}_{d-1})}{2} \Gamma\left(\dfrac{d-m}{2}\right). \square
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thanks, but the notation is a bit obscure to me. This is the same as what I got, right?

Comment: Yours is wrong, I think. To begin with, $N = d$ and $M = m,$ and in the integral you made the change of variables $u = r^2,$ so that $u' = 2r$ and then $\int e^{-r^2} r^\alpha dr = \dfrac{1}{2}\int e^{-u} u^{\frac{\alpha - 1}{2}} du.$ I think you factored out a $2^{\frac{d - m}{2}-1}$ wrongly.

Comment: I see what's wrong. In the original question the exponent was not divided by 2, but in my answer for some reason I divided by 2. If you correct for that we are getting equivalent results.

Answer (score 0):

Introduce the spherical coordinates $r, \theta, \xi_1, \ldots, \xi_{N - 2}$,
$$ x_1 = r \cos (\xi_1), \quad x_2 = r \sin (\xi_1) \cos (\xi_2), \quad
   \ldots, \quad x_N = r \sin (\xi_1) \ldots \sin (\xi_{N - 2}) \sin
   (\theta) $$
where $0 \leqslant \xi_i \leqslant \pi$, $0 \leqslant \theta \leqslant 2 \pi$
and $0 \leqslant r < \infty$. The volume element is given by $\mathrm d x_1
\ldots \mathrm d x_N = r^{N - 1} \mathrm d r \mathrm d \sigma$, where $\mathrm d
\sigma$ is the unit-sphere surface element,

$$\mathrm d \sigma = \sin^{N - 2} (\xi_1) \ldots \sin (\xi_{n - 2}) \mathrm d \theta
\mathrm d \xi_1 \ldots \mathrm d \xi_{N - 2}$$

It follows that:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
  I & = & \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \| {\vec x} \|^{- M} \mathrm e^{- \|
  {\vec x} \|^2 / 2} \mathrm d \vec x\\
  & = & \left( \int_0^{\infty} r^{N - M - 1} \mathrm e^{- r^2/2}
  \mathrm d r \right) \left( \int_{\mathcal{S}} \mathrm d \sigma \right)\\
  & = & 2^{(N - M) / 2 - 1} \Gamma \left( \frac{N - M}{2}
  \right) \frac{2 \pi^{N / 2}}{\Gamma (N / 2)}
\end{eqnarray*}$$

where $\mathcal S$ is the unit sphere.